# Getopt does not read repetitive argument

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to get options via getopt.

I`ve run the program via the command line:

```
test.exe -ja 1:2 -ja 3:4
```

My code have following:

```
int c;
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "j:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'j': {
            printf("Find j\n");
            if (optarg[0] == 'a') {
                printf("Find a\n");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `case 'j'` triggered only once, not twice. What should i change to read every `-ja` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

`If there are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1.`

When you pass `test.exe -ja 1:2 -ja 3:4`, you are passing multiple option elements (`a` and `1:2`) to a single option `j`. As they are not quoted, `getopt()` finds option `j` and sets `optarg` to point at `a`, the first character of the option element.

It then finds `1:2` which is not an option and returns `-1`.

Quote your arguments like `test.exe -j "a 1:2" -j "a 3:4"` and it's triggered twice:

```
test.exe -j "a 1:2" -j "a 3:4"
Find j
Find a
Find j
Find a
```